# Validate Symfony 2.5 form on client side (javascript - not only HTML5)

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

Does anyone know how to validate form on client-side using javascript. HTML5 validation it's not enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using JsFormValidatorBundle:

[Github repo](https://github.com/formapro/JsFormValidatorBundle)

[Packagist page](https://packagist.org/packages/fp/jsformvalidator-bundle)

Hope this help. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

My recomendation will be that you use this plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/, it's great and really easy to use. You'll have to write some minimal javascript or go with data-* elements. See this example http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/custom-messages-data-demo.html

Here is an example of validation in an UserType class:

...

```
->add('email', 'text', array (
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array (
                    'placeholder' => 'Email',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    **'data-rule-required' => 'true'**
                )
```

...

Comment: It's possible to use validation rules defined in Symfony2?

Comment: As far as I know, the answer is no, at least with jquery-validation. But I have never tried JsFormValidatorBundle.

Comment: Why the downvote?? The question is about js validation. 3 years ago, jquery-validation was a great!!!